# Concat a particular XML tag element content on multiple occurance using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an input XML, which has to be transformed to merge the p tags and p tag with attributes, am not able get an idea on this, since the repetition could be dynamic.. And also the rest of the XML content has to be copied as is,

Input XML:

```
    <Node1>
      <head>first</head>
      <body>Second</body>
      <p>This is initial tag.</p>
      <p merge="Y">Additional tag.</p>
      <p merge="Y">Tag1.</p>
      <p merge="Y">Tag2.</p>
      <p merge="Y">Tag3.</p>
      <p merge="Y">TagN.</p>
      <tail>third</tail>
    </Node1>
```

Expected Output XML:

```
     <Node1>
        <head>first</head>
        <body>Second</body>
        <p>This is initial tag.Additional tag.Tag1.Tag2.Tag3.TagN.</p>
        <tail>third</tail>
     </Node1>
```

p tag has to be merged with p tag with merge="y" attributes content, and its possible there could be multiple p tag with merge="y" with N number of repetitions. Is there a way, this could be merged with XSL code.

Can someone guide me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In XSLT 2 or 3 you have straight-forward tools for that with `xsl:for-each-group` and `group-starting-with` and/or `group-adjacent`. Which XSLT version or XSLT processor do you use? And you will need to explain in more detail what determines the "initial" element, the `merge=" Y"` attribute seems to be clear.

Comment: We are using XSLT version 1, and I call it via the db2 function as a WLM stored procedure. So we cannot really use Version 2 or 3... Idea is, content with the p tag and p tag with Merge attributes has to be combined together in a single XML tag...

Comment: So which other elements can occur in front of a `p merge="yes"`? What happens if the sequence of `p merge="yes"` elements is preceded by a different element than a `p`? And can there by any other elements in between those `p merge="yes"`? What happens then?

Comment: Right now our requirement is only with, p merge="yes" will be followed by p tag, and both has to be merged, there will not be any other tag occurring in between... In-case if there comes any element in between, I hope that <p> tag has to be created separately..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to key the `p merge="Y"` elements on the preceding sibling `p`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="initial-p" match="p[@merge = 'Y']" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::p[not(@merge = 'Y')][1])"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Node1/p[not(@merge = 'Y')]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | key('initial-p', generate-id())/node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Node1/p[@merge = 'Y']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiK1

As for the use of keys: the stylesheet defines the key `<xsl:key name="initial-p" match="p[@merge = 'Y']" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::p[not(@merge = 'Y')][1])"/>` which means the XSLT processor indexes the `p[@merge = 'Y']` elements on the generated id of the first preceding sibling `p` not having that `merge` attribute. Then the template for those `p` elements (i.e. `match="Node1/p[not(@merge = 'Y')]"`) is able to select the indexed `p[@merge = 'Y']` elements by calling the `key` function with `key('initial-p', generate-id())` and the `key('initial-p', generate-id())/node()` simply makes sure only the contents of those elements is processed further (which means in the context of the complete stylesheet the contents is copied by the identity transformation template).

You can find more about using keys in any XSLT text book, for instance the book "Practical Transformation Using XSLT and XPath" available online at https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm has a sub section "XSLT key node referencing" in the chapter 7, section 4.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works as expected.. Just trying to understand, select="node() | key('initial-p', generate-id())/node()" how does this merging happens using this statement, can you clear me on that please.

Comment: Hi, I would need another suggestion about , if I need to add a blank space before appending the p tags.. something like this, 
<p>This is initial tag. Additional tag. Tag1. Tag2. Tag3. TagN.</p>
Can it be done with the key function itself ?

Comment: Add a template `<xsl:template match="Node1/p[@merge = 'Y']/text()"><xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:template>` (see https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiK1/1) to make sure a space is added before the contents of the text node child of a `p[@merge = 'Y']` element.

Answer (score 0):

To merge the "initial" `<p>` element (without `merge` attribute = 'Y')
with following `<p>` elements (with `merge` attribute = 'Y'), you need
a template matching "p".

Inside this template there should be `<xsl:if test="not(@merge = 'Y')">`,
to serve **only** "initial" elements.

The instruction to copy the content should include:

- the current element,
- following `<p>` siblings with `@merge = 'Y'` (predicate No 1),
- but only "direct siblings", i.e. not preceded by another "initial" `<p>`
  element (predicate No 2),
- with empty `separator` (default is a space).

This way the script works OK even if you have another "initial" `<p>` element
with (another) following sequence of `<p>` elements to be merged (as in
my example given below).

So the XSLT script can be as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:if test="not(@merge = 'Y')">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="., following-sibling::p[@merge = 'Y']
          [generate-id(preceding-sibling::p[not(@merge = 'Y')][1])
            = generate-id(current())]"
          separator=""/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

For a working example see http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiJZ

In **XSLT 1.0** some changes are needed, because `value-of` in version 1.0
works a little other way (and does not support `separtor` attribute).
To circumvent this problem, you should use separate `value-of` for the
current element and `for-each` loop (with another `value-of`) for
following siblings.

For an example in version 1.0 see http://xsltransform.net/3MEbY7K

Comment: there are many ways to perform this in Stylesheet version 2, But my application right now support only Version1.. trying to see, if the same is possible in version 1.

Comment: In version 1.0 it is also possible. See version 1.0 example.